# the kuberentes dashboard did not redirect to login

Tags: kubernetes

I am deployment a kubernetes cluster and now I want to access the kubernetes dashboard, my route is public pc---cloud nginx --- kubernetes cluster treafik ingress--kubernetes dashboard. Beacause the nginx already have a certificate so that I do not want to use certificate in the backend in traefik or kuberenetes dashboard. This is my host nginx config:

```
[root@k8smasterone ~]# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/kubernetes.poemhub.top-443.conf 
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  kubernetes.poemhub.top;
        
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                client_max_body_size 1m;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
        }

}
```

8443 is the traefik https listening port. And this is my traefik config:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-route
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  tls:
    secretName: cloud-mydlq-tls
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`kubernetes.poemhub.top`)
      services:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          port: 9090
```

and is is my kubernetes dashboard config:

```
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
          secret:
            secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: tmp-volume
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          image: 'kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.3.1'
          args:
            - '--namespace=kube-system'
            - '--metrics-provider=none'
          ports:
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5443
              protocol: TCP
```

but the kubernetes did not redirect to login page,where is going wrong? my request path is user---nginx(443)---traefik(8000)--dashboard service(443)---dashboard(443). what should I do to enable the login page? The access url is: https://kubernetes.poemhub.top

Comment: First, I would add some `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https` in that nginx configuration (unrelated to your question). Then: would you have SELinux enabled on your reverse proxy? Do you have any other Ingress that works, or is it your first one on that cluster?

Comment: I have other ingress that works fine. @SYN

Comment: Can you curl the dashboard service from a k8s node? What about a curl against traefik web entrypoint? Any relevant logs in /var/log/nginx?